# Redirecting pages depending on location

Tags: php, redirect, geolocation

Please help me, and be patient since i'm a php virgin.

I'm using Cloudflare and want to redirect every page from outside of Indonesia to a specific page. After a few tries, I can redirect from `index.php` to each separate destination page.

But the problem comes when I put this redirect code on the destination page. It seems like it loops indefinitely. I want to keep this functionality on, because I don't want a visitor that clicks on a Google search result to end up in the wrong page.

How can I properly check the IP on every page, and if they are from `ID`, then they will be redirected to `index_id.php`. And if they are not, they will go to `index_ww.php`. This without infinite loops, because this code is in both `index_id.php` and `index_ww.php`.

```
$country_code = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];

if ($country_code=="ID"){
    $link = 'http://www.myweb.com/index_id.php';
} else {
    $link = 'http://www.myweb.com/index_ww.php';
}
header("location:$link");
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a query parameter onto the end of the destination URL, like `?redirected=1`, and always check for that parameter before performing the redirect code. Here's an example:

```
<?php

if (empty($_GET['redirected'])) {
    $country_code = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];

    if ($country_code=="ID"){
        $link = 'http://www.myweb.com/index_id.php?redirected=1';
    } 
    else {
        $link = 'http://www.myweb.com/index_ww.php?redirected=1';
    }

    header("location:$link");
    exit;
}

?>
```